# Postgres: Convert text to timestamptz for index?

Tags: postgresql

I have a column `text_ts` which is a text field that always holds data representing a `timestamptz`, just as a `text` field. I need to create an index on it such as:

```sql
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS text_ts_timestamp_idx ON my_schema.my_table ((text_ts::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'));
```

However I get the error:

```
functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE
```

I have found this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/250627/why-isnt-it-possible-to-cast-to-a-timestamp-in-an-index-in-postgresql which seems to have a recommended way to handle `timestamp`, but I can't seem to get it to work for `timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'`.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The correct solution it so to make that column a **real** `timestamptz`. **Never** store timestamp (or date nor number) values in `text` columns.

Comment: Preaching to the choir my friend. Unfortunately this is the hand I'm dealt.

Comment: The method you link to still works.  What exactly did you try, and what went wrong?

Comment: Here's where I am now, but I can't get the syntax to work. https://pastebin.com/3m50b04h Thanks!

Comment: `AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'` is not part of the data type, so it shouldn't be in the declaration.  SQL-language functions do not end with END.